# Angular Translations ngx-translate-extract invalid output file

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

According to [docu](https://github.com/biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract) of ngx-translate-extract package, I have this command:

`"extract": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output ./src/assets/i18n/{en,de}.json --clean --sort --format namespaced-json"`

Command should generate translations in two separate files (en.json and de.json). However, output is single file '{en,de}.json'

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: same here... I tried with *.json and it does not save either

Answer (score 0):

```
"extract-i18n": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output ./src/assets/i18n/pt-PT.json ./src/assets/i18n/en-US.json ./src/assets/i18n/fr-FR.json --clean --format json"
```

I set individual output for each file, and it works, it's not ideal but it's a workarround